# Ignore images when converting word document to text using Interop in C#

Tags: c#, office-interop, docx

Currently my code successfully converts all the text in a word document (.docx) into plain text in a .txt file but wherever there is a image in the word doc it gets replaced by a '/' in my output file. How can I ignore the images?

My code stub:

```
Word.Application app = new Word.Application();
Word.Document doc;
object missing = Type.Missing;
object readOnly = true;
doc = app.Documents.Open(ref path, ref missing, ref readOnly, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing); 
string text = doc.Content.Text;
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(txtPath, text);
Console.WriteLine("File converted to .txt!");
```

Comment: Hmmmm I'm not sure if Content object has the ability to do that.  Might just have to replace those characters when reading out the text. 

    string text = doc.Content.Text.Replace("'/'","");

Or do you explicitly need to ignore the images on the initial read from the Content?

Comment: If I do the replace method I may lose any '/' characters that were in the original word file so I assume my best bet is to ignore on the initial read... unless there is a better method.

Comment: Ah okay I was reading that as the images being replaced "including" the single quotes around the forward slash which I thought would have been a rare occurrence.

Comment: What are all these `ref missing` doing in your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different approach instead of the one I suggested above

Just save the document as text

```
object path = txtPath; 
const int wdFormatText = 2;
object fileFormat = wdFormatText;
doc.SaveAs (ref path, ref fileFormat, ref missing, ...) // other missing parameter
```

There is also a method `SaveAs2`, which I assume will be the same if you keep on pass `missing` for the further parameters

Answer (score 2):

What about removing all the images before accessing Content?

Something like this:

```
while (doc.InlineShapes.Count > 0)
{
    doc.InlineShapes(1).Delete();  //Collection is 1-based, first element is 1, not 0; at least when using it within VBA (weird language...)

}
// and with Shapes as well
while (doc.Shapes.Count > 0)
{
    doc.Shapes(1).Delete();
}

string text = doc.Content.Text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution. This class read a Word document, remove all images and then convert it to a RTF file.

```
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
using System.IO;
using OW = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;

namespace WordImagesCruncher
{
    public class WordImagesCruncher
    {
        public string SourceFilePath { private set; get; }

        public WordImagesCruncher(string sourceFilePath)
        {
            SourceFilePath = sourceFilePath;
        }

        public void DoWork()
        { 
            var wordApp = new OW.Application();
            OW.Document doc = wordApp.Documents.Open(SourceFilePath);

            for (int i = doc.InlineShapes.Count; i > 0; i--)
            {
                doc.InlineShapes[1].Delete();
            } 

            for (int i = doc.Shapes.Count; i >0 ; i--)
            {
                doc.Shapes[1].Delete();
            }

            doc.SaveAs(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(SourceFilePath) + "_tmp.rtf", OW.WdSaveFormat.wdFormatRTF);
            doc.Close();
            wordApp.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

Don't forget to add the Interop reference

[image]

and change the property `Embed Interop Types` to `Yes`.